# How to pass a route parameter to a custom password reset notification in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

I have defined custom routes for password reset, which has a route parameter

```
Route::post('{school}/password/email', 'Web\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('{school}/password/reset', 'Web\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('{school}/password/reset', 'Web\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset.submit');
Route::get('{school}/password/reset/{token?}', 'Web\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
```

Wondering how to pass the `school` route parameter to the `sendPasswordResetNotification` inside my user model where I have specified the custom notification for password reset

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $school = ''; //How do I access the school route parameter in here? Is there a way to pass the route parameter to the sendPasswordResetNotification function?
    $this->notify(new SchooUserPasswordResetNotification($token, $school));
}
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it through the `request` helper method like:

```
request()->route()->parameter('school')
```

Example:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $school = request()->route()->parameter('school');
    $this->notify(new SchooUserPasswordResetNotification($token, $school));
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. This is what I was after. Cheers!